# Deploying multiple AWS lambdas separately

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I'm using Serverless Framework 1.32.0 with AWS Lambdas and Python 3.6. I would like to deploy multiple lambdas in a separate way, since at this moment I can only do deployments one by one for every lambda in my directory, which can be confusing with many lambdas in a short future.

This is my current project structure:

```
└── cat_service
    │   
    ├── hello_cat
    │   ├── hello_cat-functions.yml
    │   └── service.py
    │   
    ├── random_cat_fact
    │   ├── random_cat_fact-functions.yml
    │   └── service.py
    │   
    └── serverless.yml
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: cat-service 

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  stackName: cat-service
  deploymentBucket:
    name: test-cat-bucket
  role: arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:role/lambda-cat-role
  cfnRole: arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:role/cloudformation-cat-role

functions:
  - ${file(lambdas/hello_cat/hello_cat-functions.yml)}

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    catStateMachine:
      definition:
        Comment: "Get cat hello"
        StartAt: hello_cat
        States:
          hello_cat:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:${self:service}-${opt:stage}-hello_cat"
            End: true

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
```

**hello_cat-functions.yml**

```
msc_cat_facts:
  handler: service.handler
  name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-msc_cat_facts
```

The problem is that, when I deploy it with `serverless deploy --stage dev`, it zips the full project and does not separate lambdas, so the actual Lambda in the AWS console shows as `hello_cat` but includes the full project structure instead of separating every lambda files in its own directory.

Is there a way to deploy separate lambdas in the same project with only one `serverless.yml`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to configure Serverless to [package individually](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/)

To do this add the following to your `serverless.yaml`:

```
package:
  individually: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that approach but didn't work, for some reason creates a main lambda with the two others inside of it, instead of separating them. My implementation was as mentioned in https://forum.serverless.com/t/is-this-expected-behavior-for-individually-packing-functions/330/4

Comment: Hi Carlos, did you find a solution for this? I am facing this same issue currently.

Answer (score 0):

Besides including into `serverless.yml`, as proposed by @thomasmichaelwallace, the:

```
package:
    individually: true
```

Try changing the path of your handler function into **hello_cat-functions.yml**, 
from `handler: service.handler` to:

```
msc_cat_facts:
   handler: hello_cat/service.handler
   name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-msc_cat_facts
```